# Hide queried results depending on url

Tags: php

I am wanting to hide a result depending on the id of the product page I am viewing. To be clearer, I have a single product page which also shows 'related' products from the same category underneath. What I would like to do do is hide the product I am looking at from those related product results. I have tried to do this by getting the id and then doing a query on that result, turning it into a class and then hiding it but it ignores my style.

I am doing a query on gender to show my related products, they are either in mens or womens:

```
if($gender == 'mens' || $prodIdRel === $prodIdRel){
    echo relatedMensProducts();
} else if($gender == 'womens'){
    echo relatedWomensProducts();
}

if($product_id == $product_id){
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
    <?php echo'.' . $$product_id ?>{
        display:none!important;
    }
    </style>
    <?php
}
```

So for instance, If I am looking at single_product.php?product_id=23 and I want to hide product id 23 from the related products query.

**EDIT**

```
function relatedMensProducts(){
global $conn;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE gender = 'mens' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo '<div class="product ' . $row['product_id'] . '">';
            echo '<a class="' . $row['product_id'] . '" href="single_product.php?product_id=' . $row['product_id'] . '">';
            echo '<img src=' . $row['product_img'] . ' />';
            echo '<div class="title">'. $row['product_name'] .'</div>';
            echo '<div class="title">'. $row['product_price'] .'</div>';
            echo '</a>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    } else{
    echo "0 Results";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add an optional param to relatedMensProducts() to accept id which to ignore?

Comment: Also how do you display items, post code please

Comment: @ka_lin hey I have updated my question

Comment: It seems you are declaring the hidden class but when you display items you are not putting that class...wrap your whole item in a div with your hidden class (add a div before the img tag and close at the end)

Comment: @ka_lin I do apologise I have just edited again which is the code for the function